# Run Code From PC

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

https://www.ev3dev.org/projects/2014/05/09/Python-Rubiks-Cube-Solver/

```
The other one gives a solution in around 20 steps, but takes around 500 MB of memory, so I need to run it on a computer
```

How do I run a code from my computer?

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()

if hostname == 'ev3dev':
    # We are on the EV3, import required modules directly
    import ev3dev.ev3   as ev3
    import ev3dev.fonts as fonts
    import PIL
    import os, subprocess
    ev3.Sound.beep().wait()
else:
    # We are somewhere else. Assume we are using RPyC:
    import rpyc
    conn  = rpyc.classic.connect('192.168.15.3')
    ev3   = conn.modules['ev3dev.ev3']
    fonts = conn.modules['ev3dev.fonts']
    PIL   = conn.modules['PIL']
    os    = conn.modules['os']
    getpass    = conn.modules['getpass']
    locale    = conn.modules['locale']
    #sys   = conn.modules['sys']
    namepc = getpass.getuser()
    name = (namepc.title())
    print(name)
    cv2    = conn.modules['cv2']
    subprocess   = conn.modules['subprocess']
    ev3.Sound.beep()
```

I've tried this code but to import cv2 takes around 2-5 minutes or shows "result expired"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definetley possible on Ev3, even with the older mindstorms NXT.

This link should get you started: https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/connecting-to-ev3dev-with-ssh/

Also instead of puTTY there is MobaXTerm:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfhqZGFJd9A